# How can I create a widget against a background image that is touchable and dragable?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create an application that has a background image with widget like objects that can be touched and dragged.  Think of a chess set app where you can touch and drag a chess piece to the target square.  I've poured over the samples but I just can't seem to get it.  I thought widgets might be the answer, but they are more for home screen like apps.  I thought TouchRotateActivity in the samples would have the answer, but I can't get it to run so I can see if it behaves the way I want.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by creating a View and using a Drawable or Bitmap for the Touchable objects.  In the `onDraw(Canvas)` method of the View you can "draw" your Touchable at the desired positions.  Then override the `onTouchEvent()` to change the position of the Drawable. Here's a **very basic** example:

`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // The View
        SampleView myView = new SampleView(this);
        myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        rl.addView(myView,
              new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        setContentView(rl);
     }

    // The View for drawing and moving
    class SampleView extends View
    {
        private static final String TAG = "SampleView";
        // Track the Touch
        float mLastX = 0;
        float mLastY = 0;
        boolean mDragging = false;

        // Used to draw the square
        ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        // Square size
        int mSquareWidth = 50;

        public SampleView(Context ctx)
        {
            super(ctx);
            this.mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            int x = (int)this.mLastX;
            int y = (int)this.mLastY;
            // Set the Bounds of the Square
            this.mDrawable.setBounds(x,y,x+mSquareWidth,y+mSquareWidth);
            // Draw it
            this.mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            int action = event.getAction();
            float x1 = event.getX(0);
            float y1 = event.getY(0);
            switch (action)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Check if you're touching in the Square. Only move the Square
                    // if we're touching in it.
                    Log.i(TAG,"DOWN");
                    if (this.mDrawable.getBounds().contains((int)x1,(int)y1))
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG,"IN BOUNDS");
                        this.mDragging = true;
                        this.mLastX = x1;
                this.mLastY = y1;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(this.mDragging)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG,"DRAGGING");
                        // If we're dragging it, offset the draw points
                        this.mLastX = x1;
                        this.mLastY = y1;
                        this.invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Stop dragging
                    this.mDragging = false;
                    break;
            }
        return true;
      }
   }
}
```

`